# PostgreSql Function "Insert data from a table to an other"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a function in PostgreSQL that would make the following:

First of all read some data from a table lets say “Select col1,col2 from table1”
Then for each row of the above selection I want to make an insert to an other table lets say table2 (that contains some extra columns like date and so on).

For each insertion I want a unique key that starts from a given number and is increased in every new row.
Can someone give me an example about how I can do it?

I need to be more specific
I want to do what is discribed below:

```
    For(every row in table1)
       if(table1.col1>0)
          insert into table2 (c1,c2,c3,c4) nalues (id,table1.col1,table1.col2,'oposite',current_timestamp)
       else if(table1.col1<0)
          insert into table2 (c1,c2,c3,c4) nalues (id,table1.col1,table1.col2,'negative',current_timestamp)

id+=1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
insert table2(id, col1, col2)
select startingpoint-1+row_number() over (order by col1, col2), 
       col1, 
       col2 
from table1
```

Comment: I have some extra data so I want a for loop that will be run for every row of table1

Comment: @user1392203: that statement ***will*** run for every row in table1. The statement does exactly what you asked for. If you do have a serial column, simply leave out the id column in the INSERT (and select) part. PostgreSQL will then populate it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [select into](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) to do this, just set up the second table with an autoincrementing field and it will give you your unique key.

Comment: The application is using hibernate and there is a sequence that gives the unique keys in every row of the tables